# DevExpress PropertyGridControl CustomEditor assignment

Tags: c#, devexpress, propertygrid

Want to assign CustomEditor to PropertyGridControl. If I try using default way it does not work, however I am trying alternative which is not suitable for my case.

Class and Custom editor which is needs to be assigned to PropertyGridControl:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {

    }

    public Language LanguageOfFoo { get; set; }
}

public class Language
{
    public Language()
    {

    }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class RepositoryItemForLanguage : RepositoryItemLookUpEdit
{
    public RepositoryItemForLanguage()
    {
        this.Columns.AddRange(new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.LookUpColumnInfo[] {
        new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.LookUpColumnInfo("Name", "Name")}
        );
        this.DisplayMember = "Name";

        List<Language> tmpList = new List<Language>();

        tmpList.Add(new Language { ID = 1, Name = "AZE" });
        tmpList.Add(new Language { ID = 2, Name = "ENG" });
        tmpList.Add(new Language { ID = 1, Name = "RUS" });

        this.DataSource = tmpList;
    }
}
```

Default way:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    propertyGridControl1.Rows.Clear();
    propertyGridControl1.DefaultEditors.Clear();
    propertyGridControl1.RepositoryItems.Clear();
    propertyGridControl1.SelectedObject = null;

    Foo f1 = new Foo();
    f1.LanguageOfFoo = new Language();


    RepositoryItemForLanguage repItem = new RepositoryItemForLanguage();
    propertyGridControl1.RepositoryItems.Add(repItem);
    propertyGridControl1.DefaultEditors.Add(typeof(Language), repItem);

    propertyGridControl1.DefaultEditors.AddRange(new DevExpress.XtraVerticalGrid.Rows.DefaultEditor[] {
    new DevExpress.XtraVerticalGrid.Rows.DefaultEditor(typeof(Language), repItem)});

    propertyGridControl1.RepositoryItems.AddRange(new RepositoryItem[] { repItem});

    propertyGridControl1.SelectedObject = f1;
}
```

Alternative method:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    propertyGridControl1.Rows.Clear();
    propertyGridControl1.DefaultEditors.Clear();
    propertyGridControl1.RepositoryItems.Clear();
    propertyGridControl1.SelectedObject = null;

    Foo f1 = new Foo();
    f1.LanguageOfFoo = new Language();


    RepositoryItemForLanguage repItem = new RepositoryItemForLanguage();
    propertyGridControl1.RepositoryItems.Add(repItem);
    propertyGridControl1.SelectedObject = f1;

    propertyGridControl1.GetRowByFieldName("LanguageOfFoo").Properties.RowEdit = repItem;
}
```

As you see it is possible only with "GetRowByFieldName" methods and specifying exact property name.

Appreciate for your help.

Comment: Why can't you use GetRowByFieldName?

Comment: @KiNeTiC, if the property name changes in the future, then I have to come refactor and it will be time consuming. Thanks.

Comment: well you can access the rows this way too : `propertyGridControl1.Rows["rowName"].Properties.RowEdit...` where rowName is the row object name.

Comment: About your "default way", have you set UseDefaultEditor to true in OptionsBehavior?

Comment: Also, these lines are probably useless : `propertyGridControl1.RepositoryItems.Add(repItem);

    propertyGridControl1.DefaultEditors.AddRange(new DevExpress.XtraVerticalGrid.Rows.DefaultEditor[] {
    new DevExpress.XtraVerticalGrid.Rows.DefaultEditor(typeof(Language), repItem)});

    propertyGridControl1.RepositoryItems.AddRange(new RepositoryItem[] { repItem});`

Comment: The only one you need is this one : `propertyGridControl1.DefaultEditor.Add(typeof(Language), repItem)});`

Comment: @KiNeTiC, hopefully you are not reading my question attentively. As I wrote, DefaultEditors is not working and I am not happy with using GetRowByFieldName.

Comment: DefaultEditors should work, so there is obviously something wrong with your code, that's why I was trying to help you fix it.